# How do I shallow clone a repo on a specific branch?

Tags: git, continuous-integration, git-branch, git-clone, shallow-clone

How do I shallow clone a git repository, so that my clone contains only 1 history item, and starts on a specific branch?

I know how to do a shallow clone:

```
git clone --depth 1 https://path/to/myrepo.git
```

but not start the clone on a specific branch.

Answer (score 179, accepted):

To clone repo *foo.git* with branch *bar* do:

```
git clone --depth 1 https://path/to/repo/foo.git -b bar
```

See the git-clone documentation: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clone.html

Comment: You can use --no--single--branch instead -b bar, to download first commit form ALL branches.

Comment: I think you mean `--no-single-branch` and not `--no--single--branch`.

Comment: The more verbose version of `-b` is `--branch`