# Cloning Repo w/ Specific Branch in Jenkinsfile

Tags: git, jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to clone using a specific branch from a gitlab repo in my jenkinsfile but I am not sure as to how I would do this. The 'branch' parameter only accepts defaults like 'master' so I can't use that. All help is appreciated, thanks

Tried using git params and setting build params

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I shallow clone a repo on a specific branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21833870/how-do-i-shallow-clone-a-repo-on-a-specific-branch)

Comment: If that doesn’t help please edit the question to add details as to why. E.g. `so I can't use that` - why not? `Tried using git params` - what have you tried and what was the result?

Comment: So essentially, I am trying to clone my repo from Gitlab in a Jenkinsfile. Once I clone it, I am going to build a docker image off the dockerfile in the repo.

Comment: Please action the previous comment :)